# How to mock a service using wiremock

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock

I am trying to mock my ServiceA using Wiremock. But seems like there is some setup missing . I am getting this error :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /__files/serviceA/endpointA Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.4.v20170414</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

404 mean that its not finding the endpoint location.

Are there any step by step tutorial that can explain how to setup the service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There some different ways:

1. run the standalone process from the command line:
   `java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.8.0.jar` (see
   http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/)
2. create a simple maven project with following dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
       <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Then create a main class that runs it:

   ```
   private static final WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(options().port(8080));

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       server.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/localsave")).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK)));
       server.start();
       //do some stuff
   }
   ```
3. Use a JUnit-Rule:

   ```
   @Rule
   public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(options().port(8888).httpsPort(8889));
   ```

You can find all information here: http://wiremock.org/docs/

Please let me know if this is enough information for you.

Comment: Thank you very much . This is very helpful. What you explained was for standalone server what if I have to run my mock service with the other service at the start up time just for my tests?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, what you are trying to test? Do you use JUnit for your tests?